# Convert data in one column and populate another column

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion

I have database with a column (DataDate) which is taking data of date type in the format YYYY-MM-DD, I have a second column called (eventdatesid) which accepts integers. I need to run a conversion that takes the data in the (DataDate) column converts it to an integer and populates the (eventdatesid) column.

What I have

DataDate

2020-01-01

2020-01-02

What I need

DataDate               eventdatesid

2020-01-01              20200101

2020-01-02              20200102

Comment: I suggest having a look at aptly named the [`CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function. Specfically take the time to pay attention to the style codes.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare         @dt date='2020-01-01';

select cast(convert(char(8), @dt, 112) as int) int_dt;
```

Results

```
int_dt
20200101
```